# How to disable a button and clear an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, list, conditional-statements

i have some button and arraylist, my button have condition

```
if(list.isEmpty){ 
   button.setEnabled(false)  
}
```

and `textTotalFinalPrice` set value to `0`

but in my case , that function actually working **BUT** must be have 2 click to set value `textTotalFinalPrice` and disabling `button`.

if just 1 click `ArrayList` not clearing data

> i have try `list.clear();` still not working

code :

```
    public void calculateTotalPrice(){
        activity.header.grandTotalPrice();
        activity.textTotalFinalPrice.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("id", "id")).format(activity.header.getFinalTotal()));
    }

    private void conditionCartsSize() {
        if (activity.header.getCarts().isEmpty()){
            activity.textFinishOrder.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            activity.textFinishOrder.setEnabled(true);
            activity.textFinishOrder.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                PrintHelper.bluetoothPrint(activity, activity.header);
                calculateTotalPrice();
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setTitle("Pesanan Berhasil")
                        .setMessage("Silahkan Ambil Struk Anda")
                        .create();

                dialog.show();
                activity.header.getCarts().removeAll(activity.header.getCarts());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
        }
    }
```

i will be appreciate your answer

Comment: try checking the size, if it is zero

Comment: i have try that , but getting same problem to. btw ```isEmpty``` == ```list.Size() == 0``` , its just simplify

Comment: show some more code

Comment: no any problems in another code, just how to clearlist

Comment: clear list and init a new one using `new Arraylist();` and see

Comment: can u give me some example in answer column?

Comment: I mean just instantiate a new arraylist to be sure that the rest of the code is fine

Comment: you might missed some code, are you trying to let the list notify its empty state to button? The first time the click was invoked, the list was clear and it's the second time that the program went to this method and found the list was empty, then the button was disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: ah i see , just a little customization. thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

check `size` of `getCarts()` in if condition as below

```
  private void conditionCartsSize() {
        if (activity.header.getCarts().size>0){
            activity.textFinishOrder.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            activity.textFinishOrder.setEnabled(true);
            activity.textFinishOrder.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                PrintHelper.bluetoothPrint(activity, activity.header);
                calculateTotalPrice();
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setTitle("Pesanan Berhasil")
                        .setMessage("Silahkan Ambil Struk Anda")
                        .create();

                dialog.show();
                activity.header.getCarts().removeAll(activity.header.getCarts());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: if ```getCarts(),size > 0``` button will be always disabled , re-check my questions

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

Just iniatialize new ArrayList with a Little Customization Like This :
`activity.header = new Header(0,0,0,0,0,0,new ArrayList());`